# Column name based on another column's value

Tags: ms-access

I have a table with 4 columns in access. The column names are [index,department,column1,column2]. "column1" and "column2"'s name can vary depending on the department. What will be an efficient and intuitive way to display multiple column names for "column1" and "column2" based on department?

```
index   department  column1 column2
1             dptA   123    345
2             dptB   456    hello
3             dptC   789    world
```

The problem may be confusing but I am glad to answer any questions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you'll need some code in the background to change the field's labels on your forms.  I can't imagine that you want to actually change the field names constantly in the base table.

Changing labels on forms is pretty simple though:

`If Me.Department = "dptA" then
  Me.Column1Label = "Whatever"
End If`

...Where Department is the name of the control with the value for department and Column1Label is the label control's name on the form.